# c3 JS scroll bar jumping when loading new data

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, d3.js, c3

We are using c3 as a wrapper around d3 javascript charting library. You can see even [in their own demo](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html) when the data is updated the scroll bar flickers momentarily.

This isn't a problem when there is already a scrollbar on the page as it is in their case. But if the page is smaller the addition and sudden removal or the scrollbar can be jarring.

We aren't doing anything wildly different than they do in their examples. The mystery is why the scrollbars jump. Any ideas? If you want to look at my code it is blow:

---

Data is getting passed to our AngularJS Directive using SignalR

```
$scope.$watch('data', function () {
    normalizedData = normalize($scope.data);

    chart.load({
        columns: getChartDataSet(normalizedData)
    });
});
```

After we take the normalized data it simply gets set into an array then passed to C3

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: d3.select($element[0]),
    data: {
        type: 'donut',
        columns: [],
        colors: {
            '1¢': '#2D9A28',
            '5¢': '#00562D',
            '10¢': '#0078C7',
            '25¢': '#1D3967',
            '$1': '#8536C8',
            '$5': '#CA257E',
            '$10': '#EC3500',
            '$20': '#FF7D00',
            '$50': '#FBBE00',
            '$100': '#FFFC43'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        show: true  
    },
    size: {
        height: 200,
        width: 200
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        item: {
            onmouseover: function (id) {
                showArcTotal(id);
            },
            onmouseout: function (id) {
                hideArcTotal();
            }
        }
    },
    donut: {
        width: 20,
        title: $scope.label,
        label: {
            show: false,
            format: function(value, ratio, id) {
                return id;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd guess the SVG element is momentarily resized to height zero. Can you step through the C3 code with a debugger and see if/when that happens?

Comment: yep, I've been trying that to no avail, The svg never collapses or anything

Comment: There is an svg element appending to the bottom of the <body>. Not sure why the c3 library is appending it. Often, people do that to calculate relative size for other elements and to use exact pixel sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When C3 draws the chart it appends an SVG at the bottom of the `<body>` element, even with `style="visibility:hidden". I just added a CSS class

```
body > svg { height:0px !important }
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

*body > svg { height: 0; }* did not help me. But I had experimented a bit and found a solution:

```
body > svg {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;
    top: 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this method can't fix the issue if a window's height is too small.

Also, you can get rid of jumping by adding scrollbar by default:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of putting a scrollbar on there when it isn't necessary. Unfortunately custom style on the SVG seems to be whats needed